# How can I get a stereo cameras volume and parameters?

Tags: python, camera

I need to find some parameter of the stereo camera.
In particular I need:

- The distance of the near and far plane and where are them (for calculate the dimensions, the position of the vertices of the panel, etc.)
- Where exactly is the volume of the camera situated (the volume you can see if you enable the option in the 3D view generic properties)
- The formula used to calculate this data in blender (who knows where the file with this formula is?

  ```
  import bpy

  scene = bpy.context.scene
  cam = scene.camera
  print("convergence_distance: %f" %cam.data.stereo.convergence_distance)
  print("convergence_mode: %r" %cam.data.stereo.convergence_mode) 
  print("interocular_distance: %f" %cam.data.stereo.interocular_distance) 
  print("pivot: %s" %cam.data.stereo.pivot) 
  print("focal_length: %f" %cam.data.lens)
  print("gpu_dof.focal_length: %f" %cam.data.gpu_dof.focal_length)
  print("gpu_dof.focus_distance: %f" %cam.data.gpu_dof.focus_distance)
  print("gpu_dof.is_hq_supported: %s" %cam.data.gpu_dof.is_hq_supported)
  print("lens_unit: %s" %cam.data.lens_unit)
  print("sensor_width: %f" %cam.data.sensor_width) 
  print("clip_end: %f" %cam.data.clip_end) 
  print("rotation_euler: x = {0}, y = {1}, z = {2}".format(*cam.rotation_euler))
  print("location: x = {0}, y = {1}, z = {2}".format(*cam.location)) 
  print("sensor_height: %f" %cam.data.sensor_height) 
  print("sensor_width: %f" %cam.data.sensor_width) 
  print("angle: %f" %cam.data.angle) 
  print("angle_x: %f" %cam.data.angle_x) 
  print("angle_y: %f" %cam.data.angle_y) 
  print("cam.matrix_local")
  print(cam.matrix_local)
  print("cam.matrix_basis")
  print(cam.matrix_basis)
  print("cam.matrix_world")
  print(cam.matrix_world)
  print("cam.calc_matrix_camera(x=1, y=1, scale_x=1.0, scale_y=1.0)")
  print(cam.calc_matrix_camera(x=1, y=1, scale_x=1.0, scale_y=1.0))**
  ```

with this code i have some camera parameters but i don't know how to find the others.

tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in [properties_data_camera.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_data_camera.py) can give you clues to most of the camera properties.

The volume options for the 3DView are displayed with code in [space_view3d.py](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py$2986) and use properties within the 3DView data eg. `context.space_data.show_stereo_3d_volume`.

The volume pyramid drawn for this option is based on a pyramid created from the camera location/rotation, using `cam.lens` which is shown to the user as focal length and `cam.sensor_width` (sensor size). The `cam.clip_start` and `cam.clip_end` define where the top and bottom of this pyramid are. The actual c-code that does the drawing can be found in [drawobject.c](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/drawobject.c$1875)

The location of the convergence plane is based on `stereo.convergence_distance` and looks to use the same calculations as `clip_start` with the outer edges based on the same volume pyramid.